# Orthogonal complement of submodules of free modules

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be an regular $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, $M$ a free $R$-module of finite rank and $N$ a free submodule of $M$ of finite rank. Let $(-,-)$ be a *non-singular* (meaning the induced morphism from $M$ to $M^\vee$ is bijective), symmetric bilinear form on $M$ such that its restriction to $N$ is also non-singular. We know that if $R$ is a PID, there exists an orthogonal complement of $N$ in $M$ i.e., a submodule $N^\perp$ of $M$ such that $N \cap N^\perp=\emptyset$ and $N \oplus N^\perp=M$. Is this still true if we drop the condition that $R$ is a PID? Is there any known conditions on $R$ (other than when it is PID) under which the orthogonal complement exists?

P.S. By orthogonal, I mean $(N,N^\perp)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true over any ring (and I'm not really sure how one would give a proof for PIDs which wouldn't immediately generalize to any ring...).  Define $N^\perp=\{x\in M:(x,y)=0\text{ for all }y\in N\}$.  Since the bilinear form induces an injection $N\to N^\vee$, $N\cap N^\perp=0$.  Now for any $x\in M$, define $\varphi_x:N\to R$ by $\varphi_x(y)=(x,y)$.  Since the bilinear form induces a surjection $N\to N^\vee$, there exists some $x'\in N$ such that $\varphi_x=\varphi_{x'}$.  The element $y=x-x'$ is then in $N^\perp$ and $x=x'+y$.  Thus every element of $M$ can be written as a sum of an element of $N$ and an element of $N^\perp$, so $M=N\oplus N^\perp$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand.